# Optimization in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization, maple

I am wondering if anyone could tell me the coding in mathematica. I have the Maple coding as follow:

```
with(Optimization):
objectiveFunction := 0.30x1 + 0.15x2

N: = 0.04x1 + 0.08x2 >= 25.4
P: = 0.08x1 + 0.04x2 >= 26.4

Solve(N,x2)
Solve(P,x2)

Plot([-0.5x1 + 320, -2x1 + 960], x1 = 200..1500, x2 = -200...1500)
```

Comment: findminimum or nminimize.

Comment: I still don't understand how to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the objective function and constraints almost as an in Maple, except that your symbols shouldn't start with capital letters, as those are reserved for Mathematica keywords, line `N`:

```
objectiveFunction = 0.30 x1 + 0.15 x2;
n = 0.04 x1 + 0.08 x2 >= 25.4;
p = 0.08 x1 + 0.04 x2 >= 26.4;
```

Then you can simply pass those to FindMinimum

```
{objectiveValue, solution} = FindMinimum[{objectiveFunction, n, p}, {x1, x2}]
```

> Out[...] = {99., {x1 -> 228.333, x2 -> 203.333}}

(you can also use `NMinimize`; `FindMinimum` uses local, gradient based optimization methods like Newton's, `NMinimize` attempts global optimization. In this case, both functions should figure out that it's a linear programming problem.)

I'm not sure what your plot is doing, but I can try to visualize the result:

```
Show[
 ContourPlot[objectiveFunction, {x1, 200, 1500}, {x2, -200, 1500}],
 RegionPlot[n && p, {x1, 200, 1500}, {x2, -200, 1500}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity[0.2]], 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]],
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x1, x2} /. solution]}]]
```

[image]